# Having difficulty creating a percentage table

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, percentage, janitor

## Example Dataframe

```r
structure(list(sex = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female"), cigarettes_smoking_status = c("Non-smoker", 
"Non-smoker", "Non-smoker", "Non-smoker", "Non-smoker", "Non-smoker", 
"Non-smoker", "Regular Smoker", "Non-smoker")), row.names = 2:10, class = "data.frame")
```

## Code

```r
smoking_status_by_per <- smoking_dataset %>% 
  group_by(cigarettes_smoking_status, sex) %>%  
  dplyr::summarise(count1=n()) %>% 
  mutate(percentage=(count1/sum(count1))*100) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = percentage) %>%  
  group_by(cigarettes_smoking_status)
```

## The problem

I am having difficulty producing a percentage table in R that is condensed to 4 rows (Occasional smokers, Non-smokers, regular smokers and Prefer not to say) that clearly shows the percentage in each category by sex. Ideally, I am looking to produce a table in R that looks like this
How I want the table to look:
[image: How I want the table to look]

I have been attempting to use `janitor::tabyl` and `pivot_wider` to condense the rows, so there are just 4 rows. One row for Regular smokers. One row for occasional smokers etc. This is what my current output looks like.
Current dodgy output:

[image: Current dodgy output]

Comment: try adding to your `pivot_wider` id_cols argument (`pivot_wider(id_cols = cigarettes_smoking_status, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `proportions` and some binding to get what you have in the example.

Starting with enough data to fill out the matrix,

```r
set.seed(42)
quux <- data.frame(response = sample(c("Non-smoker", "Occasional smoker", "Prefer not to say", "Regular smoker"), size=5000, replace=TRUE), gender = sample(c("Male", "Female", "Prefer not to say", "Unknown"), size=5000, replace=TRUE))
head(quux)
#            response            gender
# 1        Non-smoker           Unknown
# 2        Non-smoker Prefer not to say
# 3        Non-smoker            Female
# 4        Non-smoker           Unknown
# 5 Occasional smoker            Female
# 6    Regular smoker           Unknown
```

## base R

We can look at a simple table with:

```r
table(quux)
#                    gender
# response            Female Male Prefer not to say Unknown
#   Non-smoker           330  294               323     312
#   Occasional smoker    308  344               287     325
#   Prefer not to say    292  337               310     304
#   Regular smoker       309  308               311     306
```

For future verification, the sum of the first column (`Female`) is 1239, and the expected column-wise percentages for that are

```r
c(330, 308, 292, 309) / 1239
# [1] 0.2663438 0.2485876 0.2356739 0.2493947
```

We can get the percentages with

```r
round(100 * proportions(table(quux), margin = 2), 2)
#                    gender
# response            Female  Male Prefer not to say Unknown
#   Non-smoker         26.63 22.92             26.24   25.02
#   Occasional smoker  24.86 26.81             23.31   26.06
#   Prefer not to say  23.57 26.27             25.18   24.38
#   Regular smoker     24.94 24.01             25.26   24.54
```

Do get the right-most (Total) and bottom summary, we'll need to bind things.

```r
tbl1 <- do.call(table, quux)
tbl2 <- 100 * proportions(tbl1, margin = 2)
tbl3 <- rbind(tbl2, `Number of Respondents` = colSums(tbl1))
tbl3
#                           Female       Male Prefer not to say    Unknown
# Non-smoker              26.63438   22.91504          26.23883   25.02005
# Occasional smoker       24.85876   26.81216          23.31438   26.06255
# Prefer not to say       23.56739   26.26656          25.18278   24.37851
# Regular smoker          24.93947   24.00624          25.26401   24.53889
# Number of Respondents 1239.00000 1283.00000        1231.00000 1247.00000

tbl4 <- cbind(tbl3, `Total %` = c(100 * proportions(rowSums(tbl1)), sum(tbl1)))
tbl4
#                           Female       Male Prefer not to say    Unknown Total %
# Non-smoker              26.63438   22.91504          26.23883   25.02005   25.18
# Occasional smoker       24.85876   26.81216          23.31438   26.06255   25.28
# Prefer not to say       23.56739   26.26656          25.18278   24.37851   24.86
# Regular smoker          24.93947   24.00624          25.26401   24.53889   24.68
# Number of Respondents 1239.00000 1283.00000        1231.00000 1247.00000 5000.00
```

And we can round the numbers:

```r
round(tbl4, 1)
#                       Female   Male Prefer not to say Unknown Total %
# Non-smoker              26.6   22.9              26.2    25.0    25.2
# Occasional smoker       24.9   26.8              23.3    26.1    25.3
# Prefer not to say       23.6   26.3              25.2    24.4    24.9
# Regular smoker          24.9   24.0              25.3    24.5    24.7
# Number of Respondents 1239.0 1283.0            1231.0  1247.0  5000.0
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
tbl1 <- tibble(quux) %>%
  count(response, gender) %>%
  pivot_wider(response, names_from = gender, values_from = n)
tbl1
# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#   response          Female  Male `Prefer not to say` Unknown
#   <chr>              <int> <int>               <int>   <int>
# 1 Non-smoker           330   294                 323     312
# 2 Occasional smoker    308   344                 287     325
# 3 Prefer not to say    292   337                 310     304
# 4 Regular smoker       309   308                 311     306

tbl2 <- tbl1 %>%
  summarize(
    response = "Number of Respondents",
    across(-response, ~ sum(.)),
    `Total %` = sum(tbl1[,-1])
  )
tbl2
# # A tibble: 1 × 6
#   response              Female  Male `Prefer not to say` Unknown `Total %`
#   <chr>                  <int> <int>               <int>   <int>     <int>
# 1 Number of Respondents   1239  1283                1231    1247      5000

tbl1 %>%
  mutate(
    across(Female:Unknown, ~ 100 * . / sum(.)),
    `Total %` = rowSums(tbl1[,-1]),
    `Total %` = 100 * `Total %` / sum(`Total %`)
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(tbl2)
# # A tibble: 5 × 6
#   response              Female   Male `Prefer not to say` Unknown `Total %`
#   <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl>               <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 Non-smoker              26.6   22.9                26.2    25.0      25.2
# 2 Occasional smoker       24.9   26.8                23.3    26.1      25.3
# 3 Prefer not to say       23.6   26.3                25.2    24.4      24.9
# 4 Regular smoker          24.9   24.0                25.3    24.5      24.7
# 5 Number of Respondents 1239   1283                1231    1247      5000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
smoking_status_by_per  %>% 
    # generate counts
    janitor::tabyl(cigarettes_smoking_status, sex) %>% 
    
    # add total row/column
    janitor::adorn_totals(where = c('row', 'col')) %>% 

    # convert counts to percentages
    janitor::adorn_percentages() %>% 
    
    janitor::adorn_pct_formatting()

 cigarettes_smoking_status Female   Male  Total
                Non-smoker  75.0%  25.0% 100.0%
            Regular Smoker   0.0% 100.0% 100.0%
                     Total  66.7%  33.3% 100.0%
```

This does convert the totals to percentages. You can use `janitor::adorn_ns` to add back counts to the percentages as well. Or save the totals after calculating the totals and add them back to the table afterwards (rbind the last row and cbind the Totals column with the counts).

Comment: That's really helpful AdroMine. Thank you. Is there any way for the percentages to be calculated based on sex? For example, so the table shows the % of females that are Non smokers, as opposed to the % of non-smokers that are female.